# How to compare and find common values from different columns in same dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare two columns and find common value sets in each column, then output the rows with the common values.

Let's say I have a dataframe with:

```
no.(col1) | Username (col2) | Referral(col3) | email(col4)

0 | john | mike | email0@email.com

1 | peter | paul | email1@email.com

2 | joan | patricia | email2@email.com

3 | mike | john | email3@email.com
```

The output would be "`0 | john | mike | email0@email.com`" and "`3 | mike | john | email3@email.com`" because they have the same values in `col2` and `col3` respectively.

Comment: But what you have in row0 and row3, ('john', 'mike') and ('john', 'milk') respectively? do you consider these two rows common value sets?

Answer (score 0):

let's consider we have a `data frame` named **df**, then one approach might be saving these two columns in different `dataframes` and then trying to compare them and find out their similarities, hence we would have:

```py
column1 = df.iloc[:,1].values
column2 = df.iloc[:,2].values
```

Then, saving all the indices in column1 where the set exists in column2

```py
equal_indices = []
for i in range(len(column1)): 
    for j in range(len(column2[or column1, since they are equal])): 
        if column1[i] == column2[j] and column2[i]==column1[j]:
            equal_indices.append(i) 
            print(i,j) 
            print(column1[i], column2[i])
```

Now `equal_indices` contains all the indices you want. Then you can delete the rows with similar columns from column1 or column2. or just return the found indices of column1 from the dataframe **df**:

```py
df.iloc[[equal_indices]]
```

Comment: It worked nicely. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy that it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas, any problem can nearly always be solved with some elegant one-liner.

But a possible not-so-elegant approach would be as follows:

1. Reset index so that it becomes a column.
2. Create a dataframe (df_A) containing the index (name it index_A) and column of interest A.
3. Create a dataframe (df_B) containing the index (name it index_B) and column of interest B.
4. Perform a merge of df_A on A and of df_B on B (left merge, for instance).

The result should contain the shared values and the corresponding indexes.